# Grails: Logging Domain Data Changes

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I need to log data changes from the table "documents" into another table "documents_log" using Grails.
Is there an easy way to do this?

I read about Audit Logging, but the documentation is poor and it logs in the same table, right?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Audit logging does not log in the same table. It logs in an `audit_log` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the GORM events:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

and implement exactly what you need.

Comment: does that permit modification of external domain objects?

Answer (score 1):

The Audit Logging plugin logs all changes to auditable domain classes into a table called AUDIT_LOG.  If your DOCUMENTS domain is the only auditable domain, then it's the only one that'll have auditable events recorded.

After installing the plugin (`grails install-plugin audit-logging`) You can make a domain class auditable by adding this "auditable" setting:

```
class Documents {
    static auditable = true
    Long id
 ...
```

According to this, the ability to change the audit table name through configuration is not yet in place:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAUDITLOGGING-30

If you're adamant about logging changes to the DOCUMENTS domain in a table named DOCUMENTS_LOG, you could probably create a synonym in your database to achieve that.  Or if you just need DOCUMENTS_LOG to be readable, create a DOCUMENTS_LOG view against AUDIT_LOG.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what you mean by "...it logs in the same table."

Comment: He seems to think that the Audit Logging plugin will put the logs in the Documents table itself, but as you pointed out, this is incorrect.